# React test fail on gitlab

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am running `react-scripts test --watchAll=false` on gitlab ci and from time to time the test is failing without log

```
$ npm run test:nowatch
> app-xxx@0.1.0 test:nowatch /builds/xxx/app-xxx
> react-scripts test --watchAll=false
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-xxx@0.1.0 test:nowatch: `react-scripts test --watchAll=false`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-xxxs@0.1.0 test:nowatch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-17T09_59_37_602Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

There are no informations in `/root/.npm/_logs/2021-02-17T09_59_37_602Z-debug.log`

Test are working great in local and passing the 2nd time on gitlab

Comment: The actual error is not here. Can you show some of the lines above containing the actual error?

Comment: There is no more log, this is the problem, I updated with the full log